# running iOS debugserver on non-jailbroken devices

Tags: debugging, ios

There are multiple [tutorials](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg/blob/e398af710e53a0547e749a6284bee99acdfba8e4/Document/0x06c-Reverse-Engineering-and-Tampering.md) on how to debug applications on jailbroken devices. These usually involves resigning debugserver, scp and running it from ssh with few tweaks to the entitlements and signature.

Is there a way to the do the same thing on non-jailbroken devices ?

Comment: I would say resign with objection IPA patch using a self signed certificate or using a developer account.